# How to search a company by access token given by linkedin api?

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=infosys

I do have an access token which is given by LinkedIn to get data. But i don't know, where  or how should i place that access token to retrieve data for the above company details in LinkedIn.
When i search the above URL i retrieve the message as:-

message "Empty oauth2 access token"

Any ideas on how to use the access token?...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the authentification guidelines:

> https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Once you are up and running you can do some sample queries following the docs:

> https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api